# How to log file following all renames?

Tags: magit

I upgraded to recently released Magit 2. There is a command `magit-log-buffer-file`. However, it logs file without `--follow` option, which makes it quite pointless for me (in our source code nearly everything has been moved around recently because of switch to Maven source layout). And I see no way of customizing options for logging anywhere.

Is it possible to log individual files following renames?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that should be improved. `magit-log-buffer-file` should either always use `--follow` or at least with a prefix argument. Please open a feature request so that I don't forget investigating the options.

**Edit** Unfortunately this does not actually work (see comments):

Meanwhile you can take advantage of the fact that `M-x magit-log-buffer-file` respects the arguments set in the log popup.

First you have to make `--follow` available from that popup:

```
(magit-define-popup-switch 'magit-log-popup ?f "Follow renames" "--follow")
```

Then show the popup <kbd>l</kbd>, set the switch <kbd>- f</kbd>, and save as default <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>. Of course that means that this argument will now be used when using suffix commands from the log popup too.

Comment: `--follow` can only be used when logging a single file in Git. So I cannot set that as a default. It also seems that I need to write it like `(magit-define-popup-switch 'magit-log-popup ?f "Follow renames" "--follow")`

Comment: A right, forgot about that. I was wondering why `--follow` was missing from the popup.

Comment: `?f` right. I forgot that I made that change only in some experimental feature branch.