# Make VC log history to follow file renames

Tags: vc, vc-mode

I like to see full file history regardless file renames (and with Java convention class name == file name several refactoring makes following history difficult).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13620/how-to-log-file-following-all-renames

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible in Emacs 26.1. You need to set the configuration variable `vc-git-print-log-follow` to `t`. The functionality was implemented in the following commit:

https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/commit/8663fad0a70e60e130ae4cd0529ead66fbad2250

That change is a workaround for [Emacs bug #8756: vc-git.el doesn't use --follow argument in vc-git-print-log](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=8756) but is not considered a full solution.

In the resulting `*vc-change-log*` buffer, not all [commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/VC-Change-Log.html) are fully working. For example `log-view-diff` (invoked by pressing `d`) and `log-view-annotate-version` (invoked by pressing `a`) do not work for commits before the rename, but `log-view-diff-changeset` (invoked by pressing `D`) does work.

Comment: Please also summarize in your answer what you expect someone to learn wrt your answer if they follow the link. This is close to being a link-only answer (it's not link-only, but it could be better). Link-only answers are typically deleted.

Comment: Great! This feature is marked for v26.1. I gave up with porting my `.emacs` and debugging issues with packages. So currently is at v25.3 ((

Comment: @Drew, thanks for the feedback. I have expanded my answer.